# How to pass query string parameter in asp.net?

Tags: c#, azure, acs

I am using Access Control service (ACS). I fetched all identity providers (ip) which i set for my application using the following code :

```
    public ActionResult IdentityProviders(string serviceNamespace, string appId)
    {
        string idpsJsonEndpoint = string.Format(Global.IdentityProviderJsonEndpoint, serviceNamespace, appId);
        var client = new WebClient();
        var data = client.DownloadData(idpsJsonEndpoint);

        return Content(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data), "application/json");
    }
```

When user click over the signin link the above code called using ajax and get the ips and display them in jquery-ui dialog. And when user click any one of the ips for login the browser redirect to the selected ip login page. After successful login the control return to my control which i set as a returnUrl. Upto this every thing is works fine.

Now what i am trying to do is to pass some values to identity provider (ip) login page and want to get back those values at my returnUrl controller. For this i searched and came to know that there is a query string parameter known as `wctx` which we can set and get the value at return url. But i dont know how to do this. Can anybody please guid me how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is relatively (pretty) easy.

Your URL for listing IdPs looks something like this:

`https://[your_namespace].accesscontrol.windows.net:443/v2/metadata/IdentityProviders.js?protocol=wsfederation&realm=[your_realm]&reply_to=[configured_return_url_for_your_rp]&context=&request_id=&version=1.0&callback=`

This is the most complete request for list of Identity Providers. Your may miss some variables (such as `context`, or `reply_to`), but what I show is the complete request.

So now you have two options:

- inclide your own `reply_to` parameter. It must be withing the configured realm. So if your realm is `https://www.mygreatapp.com/`, your default return URL would probably be something like `https://www.mygreatapp.com/returnUrl/` (if your controller to handle ACS response is `returnUrlController`. Now, you can safely change the `reply_to` to be `https://www.mygreatapp.com/returnUrl/?foo=bar`, just make sure you URL Encode the query string.
- Use the `context` parameter. It is safer to use and I would suggest using it. Now your URL for fetching list of IdPs will be something like:

  `https://[your_namespace].accesscontrol.windows.net:443/v2/metadata/IdentityProviders.js?protocol=wsfederation&realm=[your_realm]&reply_to=[configured_return_url_for_your_rp]&context=[your_custom_string_value_which_you_may_even_encrypt]&request_id=&version=1.0&callback=`

Note the now there is `context` value present in the request for IdP list ([your_custom_string_value_which_you_may_even_encrypt]). In your returnUrl handler controller, you can check for it with code similar (or equal) to the following:

```
if (ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["wresult"] != null)
            {
                // This is a response from the ACS - you can further inspect the message if you will
                SignInResponseMessage message =
                    WSFederationMessage.CreateFromNameValueCollection(
                    WSFederationMessage.GetBaseUrl(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Url),
                    ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Form)
                    as SignInResponseMessage;

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message.Context))
                {
                    // do whatever you want with the context value
                }
            }
```

You may want to perform any/more additional checks while handling the `SignInResponse` from ACS.